# PHP, пагинация, пропадает все при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: php, sql

вот PHP функция для вывода контента и Пагинаций:

```
define("PER_PAGE",15);
$page = (!isset($_GET['page'])) ? $page='0' : $page=$_GET['page'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
$page = $page*PER_PAGE;


function preview($sql,$res,$nums){
    global $page;

    $num = ceil($nums/PER_PAGE);
    $sql .= "LIMIT ".$page.",".PER_PAGE."";
    $newRes = mysql_query($sql);
     if($newRes){
        if($row=mysql_num_rows($newRes)>0){
             while ($resources = mysql_fetch_array($newRes)){
                            echo '<div class="block">';
                                echo '<a href="resource.php?id='.$resources['resources_id'].'"><h3>'.$resources['title'].'</h3></a>';
                                    $string = substr($resources['description'], 0, 300);
                                    $string = rtrim($string, "!,.-");
                                echo '<h4>'.$string.'</h4>';
                                echo '<h5>'.'Категория : '.$resources['categories'].'</h5>';
                                $author = $resources["surname"]." ".mb_substr($resources["name"],0,1,'UTF-8').".".mb_substr($resources["middlename"],0,1,'UTF-8').".";
                                echo '<h5>'.'Автор : '.$author.'</h5>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        };
            // КОД пагинации
            for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){ 
                    echo "<a class='pages' href='lib.php?categories=".$_GET['categories']."&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
                }
            // КОД пагинации
        }else{
            echo "<p class='errmsg'>По Вашему запросу ничего не найдено!</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

вот PHP функция для запроса.

```
function spec(){  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM resources
                            LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=resources.author_id
                            LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.categories_id=resources.categories_id
                            LEFT JOIN specialty ON specialty.specialty_id=resources.specialty_id
                        WHERE
                            categories.categories LIKE '%$_GET[categories]%'
                        AND
                            specialty.specialty LIKE '%$_POST[specialty]%'
                        ";
    preview($sql);
}
```

вот PHP функция для кнопки поиска.

```
 function resources() {
    $cat=$_GET['categories'];
    $spec=$_POST['specialty'];
    $key=$_POST['key'];
    $search=$_POST['search'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if($spec=="Выберите специальность" and ( empty($search) )){
            echo "<p class='errmsg'>Что ищем? или Выберите специальность</p>";
        }elseif($key=="author" and $spec!="Выберите специальность" and !empty($search)){
            fullSearch();
        }else if($key=="all"){
            if($spec!="Выберите специальность" or ( !empty($search) )){
                if(empty($search)){
                    spec();
                }else if($spec=="Выберите специальность"){
                    search();
                }else if($spec!="Выберите специальность" and !empty($search) ){
                    specSearch();
                }
            }
        }else if($key!="all" and $key!="author"){
            keySearch($key);
        }else if($key!="all" and $key=="author"){
            search();
        }
   }
}
```

Проблема:

```
 Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\apk-lib\functions.php on line 337
```

на этой линии стоит

```
 $nums = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Comment: Вместо выполнения запроса напишите `die($sql);` и смотрите, что у вас не так

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая ошибка - присвоение значения переменной через if, строчка 2:

```
$page = (!isset($_GET['page'])) ? '0' : $_GET['page'];
```

Строчка 2 не имеет смысла.

Формируете запрос - добавьте перед limit пробел, при таком стиле написания запроса не исключено слипание строк. Уберите ."" в конце запроса.

```
$sql .= "LIMIT ".$page.",".PER_PAGE."";
```

Так нельзя:

```
if($row=mysql_num_rows($newRes)>0){
```

Comment: Делая этот code-review вместо ответа на вопрос, спросите себя, почему самая первая страница таки выводится? Мне кажется, всё кроме отсутствия пробела перед `limit` не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: Это всё что вас смущает в коде?

Comment: Не до смущений тут) Просто какой смысл выносить в ответ каждую строчку этого изысканнейшего образца?

Comment: Да я такой же был, правда давно. Иногда и сейчас бывает так затуплю, что до гвоздей в ж..е) Видно же - учится. Жалко(